# CSS: Difficulty with background-position different corner offsets

Tags: css, background-position

I'm having some troubles making buttons using multiple backgrounds.  I know I can use :before and :after but I'd like to figure this out if possible.

Here is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/syren/qerUT/1/

In that, I've shown what I ultimately want it to look like.  In that one, I used

```
background-position: left top, 97% 90%;
```

Just to show what I want it to look like.  Since I want it to be able to expand gracefully to use for other buttons and for translation, I want to use this:

```
background-position: left top, right 5px bottom 5px;
```

But this isn't working.  According to the spec it should, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried doing the exact same thing.  Unfortunately, there is no real support for `right 5px bottom 5px` at this time.

What I ended up doing was taking my image and actually adding transparent pixels on the right and bottom of the image to get it into the position I wanted.  It isn't pretty but it works perfectly in any browser that supports multiple background images.

For a full list of what background features are supported by each browser, visit tne [Standardista CSS3 Background Properties page](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/).  Under background-position, it lists 4-value offset as only being supported by IE9+ and Opera 11+.  Its a real shame since this is the one CSS3 background feature that isn't supported across the board.

Comment: Thanks, thats too bad.  I couldn't find any documentation on support, have you seen any?

Comment: Added a link to my answer.  In general, I like to use http://caniuse.com/ to get a general picture and then follow the links for more details.